# Parsing .txt document which contains sections

Tags: python, parsing

In python I'm trying to parse .txt document which has construction which is described below. I need to get all lines under the section block and then do some actions other that line. Please note that this is NOT CONFIGURATION file, so I can't use standard way of parsing conf files.

```
LINE 1
LINE 2

[Section1]
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3

[Section2]
LINE 1
LINE 2
```

Comment: Is each section tagged with `[section#]`?

Comment: This seems a bit too much like "can you do my assignment for me". Please try to solve it yourself and if it does not work, paste your code and tell what exactly is the problem with it.

If the question is about finding a library that parses files with that kind of format, say it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all (for my solution), you need to split all your content and filter the empty line :

`text = filter(None, map(lambda x: x.strip(), text.split("\n")))`

Supposing your default section is called `default`,

`current_section = "default"
result_parsing  = {"default" : []} 
for line in text:
    if line[0] == "[" and line[-1] == "]":
        current_section = line[1:-1]
        result_parsing[current_section] = []
    else:
        result_parsing[current_section].append(line)`

Comment: Yup I think this code should work.